# Searching multiple values in worksheet data

Tags: excel, vba

I've followed this video to create the same search function from one sheet to the other. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S4EdPJevlA&t=33s
It is pretty much exactly what I'd like it to do. However I have it set up so that the search looks in column A ie (x,1). The code is such that it uses "=" in the search box "B3" and (x,1).

The problem is I would like to have multiple identifiers in the column A (x,1) rows and some rows will share identifiers. However currently only a single identifier can be used. I know next to nothing about VBA other than I was able to copy some of the above videos workings.

From my limited reading maybe I should be trying to implement a string VBS function? I don't know

```
Sub searchMultipleValues()
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("SRA").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("A14:K150").ClearContents

count = 0

Dim p As Long

p = 14

For x = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet1.Range("B3") Then
Sheet1.Cells(p, 1) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 2) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 3) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 3)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 4) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 4)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 5) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 5)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 6) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 6)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 7) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 7)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 8) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 8)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 9) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 9)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 10) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 10)
Sheet1.Cells(p, 11) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 11)

p = p + 1

count = count + 1

End If
Next x

End Sub
```

So ultimately what I would like is to be able to use multiple search terms in the column A rows and have some column A rows share and contain the same searchable identifiers as they may apply to different rows

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So `Sheet1.Range("B3")` should be `Sheet1.Range("B3:B9")` ?

Comment: It would help a lot here to show examples of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check multiple cells for a match with the worksheet's match function.

```
For x = 2 To lastrow
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 1), Sheet1.Range("B3:B9"), 0)) Then

        Sheet1.Cells(p, 1) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 2) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 3) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 3)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 4) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 4)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 5) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 5)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 6) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 7) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 7)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 8) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 8)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 9) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 9)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 10) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 10)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 11) = Sheets("SRA").Cells(x, 11)

        p = p + 1
        Count = Count + 1

    End If
Next x
```